# Make specific link open in a new window with jquery

Tags: jquery, window

I'm looking for the ability when a link contains, for example /schedule/ in the address, only this link will open in a new window when clicked. I have a series of 5,000+ links that need to open in a new window, which I would need to update manually (no find/replace available), which contains /schedule/ in the address field and I need them all to open in a new window.

This script will enable external links to open in a new window, but can someone please assist if the link contains /schedule/ in the address field? the external algorithm can be removed. Also, can it include a width + height constraint such as 500 x 600?

***UPDATED WITH SOLUTION***

add this to your library to append the width & height: 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/open

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("a[href*='/schedule/']").open
          ({
            width:800,
            height:600,
            location:true,
            toolbar:true,
            resizeable:true,
            scrollbars:true
          }); 
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("a[href*='/schedule/']").attr('target','_blank');
```

For width / height constraints you need to open a popup window (lookup window.open...) or use a modal window that can load external content into an iframe.

Comment: there was a syntax error. i adjusted that and I confirm this works here: 

$(document).ready(function(){ $("a[href*='/schedule/']").attr('target','_blank'); });     

also, i found this plugin to manage the height and width. works like a charm! http://plugins.jquery.com/project/open

Comment: thanks for your help Moin. you helped me sleep better last night! :)

Answer (score 0):

same as the one you have but with the Contains selector

```
$("a[href*='/schedule/']").attr('target','_blank');
```

Comment: For some reason I always forget about the `~=` selector... +1

Comment: ~= will look for /schedule/ as a word delimited by spaces. so it won't work as a url with paths most likely won't have spaces

Comment: i couldn't get this to work when I tried just now...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[@href~='/schedule/']").attr('target','_blank');
});
</script>

Comment: @Moin, you're right, the '~=' does not select the correct links, the correct one would be '*=' as you have in your answer ...